# Cis/Trans-Decalin in ChemBio3D

Tags: organic-chemistry, software

According to my organic chemistry textbook, Cis-Decalin has the two rings nearly perpendicular to one another, with the middle hydrogens cis to one another. Trans-Decalin has the ring nearly flat (planar), with the middle hydrogens trans to one another.

However, typing Cis-Decalin and Trans-Decalin into ChemBioDraw (where they appear correctly in 2D form) and copying them into ChemBio3D shows the exact opposite conformations.

Is this a bug with ChemBio3D, or a mistake in the textbook?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. I my chem3d structures look as they should.